# I want to aggregate documents in elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a huge collection of documents in elastic search and i want to group the documents and add the values for the same.

Sample document:

```
[
{
"_id": "123",
"meter_id": "1001",
"voltage": "{
  "voltage": 50
}",
"date": 2020-05-09T06:03:56Z
}

{
"_id": "1234",
"meter_id": "1002",
"voltage": "{
  "voltage": 40
}",
"date": 2020-04-10T06:03:56Z
}
]
```

Now i want to match this collection specific date range. For example dates between 2020-04-10 to 2020-05-09 and the documents matching this criteria should be grouped into a single document with common meter_id 1001 and  average voltage of all documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"voltage","_type":"_doc"}}
{"meter_id":"1001","voltage":{"voltage":50},"date":"2020-04-09T06:03:56Z"}
{"index":{"_index":"voltage","_type":"_doc"}}
{"meter_id":"1001","voltage":{"voltage":60},"date":"2020-05-08T08:03:56Z"}
{"index":{"_index":"voltage","_type":"_doc"}}
{"meter_id":"1001","voltage":{"voltage":60},"date":"2020-05-01T08:03:56Z"}
```

```
GET voltage/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "2020-04-10",
        "lte": "2020-05-09",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "by_meter_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "meter_id.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_voltage": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "voltage.voltage"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting no results by using this aggregation. I am getting empty array.

Comment: Share your mapping.

Comment: This solution works. I've got the expected answer with dynamic mapping